# charging Timer doesn't quite work?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'm writing a game where I want the character to jump after holding the spacebar to charge their jump up for a bit and then the charge will get added into the jump afterwards.

However, the code that I currently have going only works around 50% of the time, and will almost indefinitely not work if the player is holding a directional movement button down at the same time.

```
    function greenTimerHandler(e:TimerEvent){
        if(spacePressed&&downBumping){
        charge += 3;
           if(charge >= 50){
              charge = 50;
           }
        } else if(!spacePressed&& downBumping) {
           greenSlimeJump(charge);
           greenSlimeTimer.stop();
        }
     }

     //And the jump function
     function greenSlimeJump(greenCharge){
         ySpeed = greenCharge * -1.5
         slimeAmt -= Math.floor(greenCharge * 0.25);
         charge = 0;
     }
```

the downBumping is just a boolean collision value based on a hitTestPoint for the bottom of the player...

Is there any way that I can make it so that it actually runs the jump function more than it currently does? It will even keep the charge value for the next time it tries to jump and the slimeAmt value is never subtracted because the code just seems to completely skip the green jump function altogether.

Heres the downBumping code:

```
if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y +  
downBumpPoint.y, true)){
       downBumping = true;
} else { 
       downBumping = false; 
}
```

and heres the timer/ space pressed:

```
if(e.keyCode == 32 && slimeAction){
      spacePressed = true;
      if(slimeType == 1 && downBumping){
            greenSlimeTimer.start(); 
      }
}
```

Comment: When do you start greenSlimeJump and how is  spacePressed been set?

Comment: It has key up and down handlers that switch the boolean with an if else statement, standard stuff. All my other stuff works, it's just this one that's giving me trouble. Green slime jump only starts when the timer registers that space is no longer being pressed. I think I tried having it all in a timer complete function but it didn't quite work out...

Comment: I think it'd be useful to see code which starts timer and sets spacePressed, downBumping variables.

Comment: Okay no problem!

Heres the downBumping code:
if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)){
  //trace("downBumping");
  downBumping = true;
 } else {
  downBumping = false;
 }

Comment: and heres the timer/ space pressed:
if(e.keyCode == 32 && slimeAction){
  spacePressed = true;
  if(slimeType == 1 && downBumping){
   greenSlimeTimer.start();
   
  }

Comment: slime action is just a boolean thats true when slimeAmt is > 0

Comment: @JamesAllen Please post updates in your question, not in the comments.